# Animate (Expand,collapse) child component along With parent component [Angular5]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-animations

[image]

I want to achieve this(Ref. attached image) in Angular 5

There Two components User-layout and role

User-Layout Component has been used at the start of Role component.
I am able to Expand and collapse the Parent component with animations but unable to to do the same simultaneously for the child component.

Any way to trigger animation on child component from the parent component.

Comment: do you want to trigger a child component method?

Comment: By trigger i mean the animation Triggers in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication between child component and parent component you can use `@Input`, `@Output` and `EventEmitter`.

If you want to pass data from parent to child you can simply do it using `@Input` as below:

First you need to import `Input` into your child component using

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Then you need to declare an `@Input` variable in your child component

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() parentVariable: string;
}
```

Then while using the child component in you parent you need to specify the varible as an attribute as below

```
<child-component [parentVariable]="parentData"></child-component>
```

You should have a `parentData` declare in your parent component whose changes will reflect in the child component `@Input` variable `parentVariable`.

Thats all you need to do to and you need to animatation code which will trigger on the change of `parentVariable` variable.

Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`animateChild()`](https://angular.io/api/animations/animateChild) method.

Excerpt from the blog post posted by the `@angular/animations` author, Matias Niemelä, about `animateChild()`

> Now what about the situation when there is an element in the application that has an animation ready-to-go, but a parent animation runs instead? Is there a way that the parent animation can dictate when the child animation runs, how long it runs for or if it doesn't run at all?
>   [...]
>
> If these animations trigger at the same time then the parent animation will always win and the child animation will be skipped. However, using animateChild we can have the parent animation query into the child and tell it when it's allowed to animate:

[Sub Animations With animateChild](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html#sub-animations-with-animatechild)

**component.html**

```
<!-- do these two guys animate at the same time? -->
<div [@parent]="parentVal">
  <div [@child]="childVal">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**component.animations**

```
trigger('parent', [
  style({ transform: 'translate(-100px)' }),
  animate('500ms',
    style({ transform: 'translate(0px)' })),
  query('@ child', animateChild())
]),
trigger('child', [
  style({ opacity:0 }),
  animate('0.5s', style({ opacity:1 }))
])
```

Comment: does this implement on two different Component.html too?
(where my Parent is from other file and Child is in other file)

Comment: tried adding the above in .ts and .html respectively but getting error for `trigger('parent', [
      style({ transform: 'translate(-100px)' }),
      animate('500ms',
        style({ transform: 'translate(0px)' })),
      **query**('@ child', **animateChild()**)
    ]),
    trigger('child', [
      style({ opacity:0 }),
      animate('0.5s', style({ opacity:1 }))
    ])`The query() and animatechild() and the error is `[ts] Cannot find name 'query'. Did you mean 'jQuery'?
any` and `[ts] Cannot find name 'animateChild'.
any`

Comment: any specific imports required for using `query()` and `animatechild()`

Comment: `import { query, animateChild } from '@angular/animations'`